# how to link 2 LANs using 2 Ubiquiti antennas

Tags: networking, wireless-access-point, ubiquiti

We have 2 Ubiquiti antennas model "Nanobeam m5-16-5ghz"
I want to link my home network to my sister home, where she has an internet provider.
The visibility is perfect and the distance is less than one kilometre.

Her LAN network is like this :

```
192.168.1.1 : router to internet
192.168.1.20 : Nanobeam antenna [1]
192.168.1.30 and up : local DHCP machines
```

My LAN network is like this :

```
192.168.1.1 : Nanobeam antenna [2]
192.168.1.2 : local router providing wifi to my home
192.168.1.30 and up : local DHCP machines
```

Question 1: one antenna must be "AP" and the other must be "station" or not?

Question 2: both antennas must work in "router" network mode so both LANs are separated?

Supposing Q1 and Q2 answers are "yes", we come to the WLAN settings.

I set my antenna [2] to "station" mode and my sisters antenna [1] to "AP" mode.

I set her SSID to her name, my antenna sees this ESSID
and they associate correctly (-45 dBm)

My WLAN settings are easy :

```
Static IP
IP = 10.139.130.113
GW = 10.139.130.97
```

Her WLAN settings :

```
Static IP
IP = 10.139.130.97
GW = 192.168.1.1            <<<<<<<<<<<< ISP router IP [point "3"]
```

From my antena [2] I can ping hers using Ubuquiti tools.

But I have no access to 192.168.1.1, neither 8.8.8.8

It seems to me the default gateway in antena [1] does not do the trick, point "3".

I would be grateful for any ideas, URLs, improvements, comments, etc.

Comment: Why do you want both networks separated? That just complicates things a lot. If your sisters LAN has the ISP you want the nanobeams to form a transparent link so that your local lan is just an extension of your sistsers lan. In other words: The pair of nanobeams just need to act as if they are a very long cable. (I'm not familiar with these devices. I don t kno'w if such a point2point link is possible with them.)

Comment: Yes to the above and otherwise you need to connect the two networks with VPN.

Comment: Tonny : why does it complicate the configuration ? The "router" network mode of Ubiquiti antennas does just that : you have a 192.168.n.n network at home, the antena talks to other antena on another range of IPs, 10.130.n.n here. My sister has some devices on fixed IPs (as TV, a printer), I do have some fixed IPs too (a Raspberry). So it is very convenient to keep repeated IPs maybe, as 192.168.1.1

Comment: John : why do I need a VPN ? Gimme just ONE reason.

Comment: OK, lets build a one single large network - so both antenas go into "bridge" wireless mode. Back to first question : one antena must be "AP" network mode and the other be "station" network mode ?